# Incomplete for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I've started to learn java, and in some examples I've seen special for loop (not very familiar to me). It's not enhanced for loop, but it looks like this

```
for(;;i++){ do something..}
```

I don't know what it means, when I just have these semicolons o.O If someone could explain it to me, would be grateful.

Comment: If you bothered to even do a precursory google search you would already have your answer

Comment: It is complete, it just doesn't have parts which author of this code didn't need (I am not saying it is good style). In other words it is normal for loop when we don't need `initialization` and `continue condition` (so it will work infinitely, or until execution of `break` `return` or `System.exit`).

Answer (score 1):

I would read through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

As you might notice,

> The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination;
>      increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The three expressions of the `for` loop are **optional**; an infinite loop can be created as follows:
>
> ```
> // infinite loop
> for ( ; ; ) {
>
>     // your code goes here
> }
> ```

(emphasis mine)

In your example, I would expect the variable `i` would have been declared and initialized before the for loop. If there is no *termination condition*, the loop will run infinitely.
You can also have a termination condition inside a loop, something like :

```
if(i = some number) {break;} //this will break the loop
```

Similarly, the increment statement can also be declared inside a loop.

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions where the asker has done zero research or tried anything on their own, it only encourages more of the same.

Comment: @BuzzBlack I wondered the same, but "Java for loop semicolons" turns up relevant answers.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay, maybe i have made a mistake, but that's not the reason to be unpolite, or saying to other people: why did u answer him bla bla..? If u don't want to answer, just walk away. I asked in hope to get some answer, but here is hard to get anything if u didn't ask something like: Color of ball is green,  space is infinite, how to apply polimorphism... ?

Comment: @BuzzBlack I haven't downvoted you, upvoted any comments about not answering etc, and I don't think I've been rude: I just answered your question.

Comment: I know, I didn't mean u were rude, but @redFIVE. I am grateful to you and to Ashraf Iqbal. Thanks man! I appreciate it

Comment: No worries @BuzzBlack - my pleasure :-)

Comment: @BuzzBlack We are trying to help as many people as we can, but since we are volunteers most of us expect some *minimal effort from asker* and visiting official documentation/tutorial is [one of mandatory steps before asking question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). As you see from this answer such tutorial held solution to your problem which kind of confirms why we expect it. So to discourage more of such questions most of the time they are downvoted and we ask OP for more details about his confusion. Answering such questions is also discouraged because it attracts more of them.

Comment: @BuzzBlack But don't get me wrong, votes are not directed at you personally (although it may look this way) but at current state of your question. You can always edit it and improve its quality. After that we can retract our down-votes or even cast up-vote. So next time simply show [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and explain what exactly is confusing you and you should be fine.